# Male Female percentage distribution dynamic image using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

[image: Percentage distribution]

I used images of Female and Male as logo here and I'm calculating Percentage from javascript, but the images are static and I want to convert it into dynamic.

means suppose here Percentage of female is 55% percent then in image we are considering logo as half-filled and half empty. but if we get result percentage as Female 10% percent then also my logo seems same as shown in image. because it's static image. I want to make it Dynamic. 
I'm new to css, javascript.
Any Starting point or reference link will also help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: make a mask png and then you can just slide a rectangle up and down behind the image.

Comment: what have you tried, where is your code? there's a great solution to this, but I'm not doing it all for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this concept:

HTML:

```
<span class="percentage"><span style="height:45%;"></span></span>
```

CSS:

```
.percentage {
    width:41px;
    height:97px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    background:url(gray.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}
.percentage span {
    width:100%;
    height:0;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:0; bottom:0;
    background:url(blue.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}
```

Images:

[image]
[image]

[Demo Link:](http://design.codeniques.com/male/male.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use .png images with transparency and css.
Then use different containers, something like this:

```
<div class="fContainer">
    <div class="fFill" style="height:50%;"></div>
    <img class="femaleImg" src='path/to/female.png'/>
</div>
```

then style them with css:

```
.fContainer{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.fFill{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.femaleImg{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

After that, you can ajust dynamically the .fFill element height in percent, using javascript, or directly php(o whatever) on the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an answer, but now, I see it has already been answered, but I will post my JSFiddle, just in case anyone in the future finds it of interest.

It's also two images aligned on top of each other, with one image being cut off using the max-height attribute in conjunction with overflow-hidden.

[Two images](https://jsfiddle.net/v0xyydqp/)

```
var percentage = 25;
var elem = document.getElementById('greyImg');

elem.setAttribute('style', 'max-height: ' + (100-percentage) + 'px; overflow: hidden;');
```

No fancy math, this image happens to be exactly 100px high.

Answer (score -1):

If your project doesn't require high compatibility,i recommand using Css -webkit-mask.
It can cover a mask on the bottom element,so you can make this dynamic by adjusting the red or blue element's height.